# combining text files in python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine multiple text files in a directory in one file. I want to write a HEADER and END statement in the combined file. The current python script which I am using combines all the files into one, but I am not able to figure out how to write a HEADER and END statement for each of the file in the combine file.

```
filenames = ['pm.pdb.B10010001.txt', 'pm.pdb.B10020001.txt', ...]
with open('/pdb3c91.0/output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write the two lines.

```
filenames = ['pm.pdb.B10010001.txt', 'pm.pdb.B10020001.txt', ...]
with open('/pdb3c91.0/output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write("HEADER\n")
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
            outfile.write("END\n")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried writing the END statement..However, instead of writing in the END of the file, it's writing after every line.To be clearer, I am pasting below how my file should look like:                                                                   
ATOM   3374  O              
ATOM   3375  OXT         
TER    3376      LEU B 436                                                                                 
END   . It however looks like this: ATOM   3374  O /nextline/END/ ATOM 3375...hope this is clearer..

Comment: The code from my answer will write before and after each input file, not after every line. Check your code. If you want to add information to your question, you can edit it.